# Relationship between matrix sum, ranks, and singular values in Eckart-Young-Mirsky proof

Tags: proof-explanation, singular-values

I've read the [proof of the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem on WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_Frobenius_norm)) (for Frobenius norm), and I understand all of it except this one step:

$\sigma_1(A - A'_{i - 1} - A''_{j - 1}) \geq \sigma_1(A - A_{i + j - 2})$

Note that $A' + A'' = A$, and $A_{k}$ is the rank-k SVD-based approximation of a given matrix $A$ (i.e. $A_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sigma_iu_iv_i^\top$). See the reference for more context if necessary.

The article justifies this step by stating that $rank(A'_{i-1} + A''_{j-1}) \leq rank(A_{i + j - 2})$; I think I understand why this rank inequality is *true*, but I don't see how it justifies the spectral norm inequality. What am I missing?